# VeraCode static code scan of django view reports "External control of Filename or Path" on render method

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, static-analysis, dynamic-analysis

Veracode is reporting a security issue on a piece of code which seems pretty innocuous to me. The code is built with python/Django and the line in question is:

> return render(request, 'core/create-user.html', context)

The render shortcut for django is pretty standard and it expects a request object, name of template and context to be passed to template. I am not sure  why Veracode is complaining for this.

It seems it is picking up the word "create-user" from the template name and assuming it be a OS/library method being called for creating a user based on some user input and which is why it is complaining but this sounds pretty dumb to me on behalf of Veracode.

Is it really a security issue, if so why? Or is it a false positive?

Comment: Looks like a fake positive to me. Can you ask VeraCode? At their prices they should help you!

Comment: @paj28 Unfortunately I don't have the license of Veracode. My client seems to have run the veracode scan on the code base and is reporting the issue to me as a person developing the code base and hence is supposed to fix the security issue too. Throwing it back to the client would seem I have offloaded the work back to them and hence my question :)

Comment: I see. If they're a cooperative client, I would chuck it back at this point. If they're a tricky client this is quite a PITA situation as without changes your issue will still show on a rescan, and they may not accept your word that it's a false positive.

Comment: have you posted this question to the Veracode Community: https://community.veracode.com/s/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with this implementation.
It is also completely according to documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/

It seems like this Veracode result is a False Positive